# MySQL query with PHP and WHERE specification

Tags: php, mysql

With this update query if the `id` is in `chk_list` then I set `checked=1`. I want if the `id` isn't in the list to set `chk_list=0`

```
$update = "UPDATE data SET checked=1 WHERE id IN($chk_list)";

$qry = $db->query($update);
```

Is there any simple way after WHERE to set if?

Comment: You can simply set the default value of the field to 0!

Comment: Can't you just do `NOT IN`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in

Comment: Either of the 2 answers will work. I'm curious though, why do you want to update every record on a table? I've never seen a scenario like this

Comment: Hi Raul, could you clarify your question? Perhaps add some context as to what you're trying to achieve on your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function to determine value to be set. Do the following:

```
$update = "UPDATE data SET checked = (IF(id IN ($chk_list), 1, 0))";
$qry = $db->query($update);
```

**Note:** **Please** [use Prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) related issues

Comment: i want when is in list set 1 and where is not set 0

Comment: @raulpaulsen please check updated answer. Use if function

Comment: if(!$qry) {

                        echo "Updation Failed";}

Comment: is this correct?$update = "UPDATE data SET checked = (IF(id IN $chk_list, 1, 0))"; or is missing something?

Comment: please echo the $update before executing it and see what you are getting. Try to run the raw query directly using phpmyadmin or mysql workbench and check its output

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly set *checked* as 1 or 0, then the if should be in the set area
Notice that its very dangerous to update **all of the table** to the extent that MySQL by default prevents this from happening, ans you should set safe updates to 0

```
UPDATE data SET checked = IF(id IN ($chk_list), 1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this with `CASE`? Not sure pretty neat or not but seems it'll work :)

```
UPDATE data SET checked= 
CASE
  WHEN id IN ($chk_list) THEN 1
  WHEN id NOT IN ($chk_list) THEN 0
END
```

Comment: it's ok to use it in php code?it works great but i dont know if it is proper

Comment: @raulpaulsen glad it works for you. Best of luck buddy :) Happy coding

Comment: @raulpaulsen I don't see any problem on it if you use it with php